# Show excerpt on front page using the_content(); and ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, custom-fields, display

I need to show a excerpt on my home page. I have standard post and a custom post type 'webinar'. The CPT 'webinar' has a custom field, using ACF 'webinar_description' that is a an equivalent of 'description' in normal posts.

I am able to display both, by adding a filter for the 'webinar_description' like this:

```
add_filter('the_content','add_my_custom_field');
function add_my_custom_field($data) {
    $data .= get_field('webinar_description');
    return $data;
}
```

Now I have both post types displaying, but it displays the entire 'description' or 'webinar_description' field. I need to trim it at 40 words and add a '... Read More' with 'Read More' being a link to the article.

I have tried this, but it only works on the normal 'post' type field 'description' it doesn't work on my 'webinar' custom post type -> custom field 'webinar-description'

```
<?php $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 400, '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">[Read more]</a>');?>
```

How can I create a filter or function that will limit both to 400 (or whatever) characters and add the link?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone in a similar situation, but this is how I solved it. First, in functions.php make the custom post type available

```
function cpt_get_excerpt(){
    $excerpt = get_field('webinar_description');
    $excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 400);
    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
    $excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
    $excerpt = $excerpt.'... <a class="c-drkGold" href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">Read More</a>';
    return $excerpt;
}
```

Then where you want to display it, use a if/else statement based on the post type and display accordingly (this example is from static front page).

```
<?php 
    if( get_post_type() == 'post' ) {
        ?><p class="l-nmb"><?php
        $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 400, '... <a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="c-drkGold">Read more</a>'); ?> </p>
    <?php } else {
        ?><p class="l-nmb"><?php
        $content = cpt_get_excerpt(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 400, '... <a href="' . get_permalink() . '" class="c-drkGold">Read more</a>'); ?> </p>
    <?php } ?>
```